# Looking for a Mega 2650 drawing or picture that shows the components labeled

Tags: arduino-mega, components

I am Looking for a Mega 2650 drawing or picture that shows the components labeled.

I've seen the schematics but didn't find a labeled assembly drawing yet.  Should this exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it exists, but not (commonly) as an "image" in the traditional sense.

You need to install Eagle PCB design software and open the PCB file downloadable from the Arduino site from where you can see exactly which component is where.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding.  I got Eagle installed and downloaded the files from the arduino website.  Thanks. It would still be nice to have a labeled picture to easily tell what the components are.